# Billing API version is less than 3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I have recently logged some errors from in app billing to crashlytics, one of them:

```
Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3
```

The OS on the devices is Android 10,11,12,13 so the devices are pretty new.

Is it possible that In-app Billing API version on new devices is less than 3?

About 200 users in last 24 hours has this error, how it possible?

UPDATE:
It happen mostly in background and seems like when I send Firebase notification(without invoking `FirebaseMessagingService`).
The billing cliend initialed in `Application` `onCreate()`

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479824/google-play-in-app-billing-api-version-is-less-than-3 and this post: https://community.revenuecat.com/third-party-integrations-53/google-play-in-app-billing-api-version-is-less-than-3-1323
In short: This error message would be thrown by Google if the user's on a very old version of the Play Store. You'll want to update your version Play Store, or ensure you are signed into a Google account on your device.

Comment: @muetzenflo How Android 13 device can be with old Google play version?